# How to remove the space between Volume(Number) and Date in customized bibliography style file?

Tags: bibliographystyle, bst

[image: output of the reference]

I have created a bibliography style file (.bst file) using cmd.

I wanted the output to look like

> H. Whitney, *Congruent Graphs and the Connectivity of Graphs*, American Journal of Mathematics, **54**(1)(1932), 150-168.

but instead, it looks like the one in the image given above (with space in between number and year)

I am unable to remove the space. I've tried to modify the .bst file manually but was unable to understand the commands. Please help!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unless you provide some more pertinent information, such as actual code chunks, chances that anybody will be able to provide a diagnosis, let alone a cure, are exceedingly slim.